# Prestashop order::getProducts: What is the price without tax and without discount?

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

In an element of `Order::getProducts()`, there are several prices:

> [total_price_tax_incl] => 1900.800000 [total_price_tax_excl] =>
> 1584.000000 [unit_price_tax_incl] => 1900.800000 [unit_price_tax_excl] => 1584.000000 [total_shipping_price_tax_incl] => 0.000000 [total_shipping_price_tax_excl] => 0.000000 [purchase_supplier_price]
> => 923.000000 [original_product_price] => 2112.000000 [original_wholesale_price] => 923.000000 [price] => 1846.000000
> [wholesale_price] => 923.000000

I'd want to pick up the one that is without tax, and without reduction.

What is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`original_product_price` is a field you're looking for :)